Retrieve Azure AD User Group Info Server-Side in Azure Web App
I'm using Azure AD for authentication in an Azure Web App. While I can access user info via the /.auth/me endpoint client-side, I need to obtain user group memberships server-side for security reasons. How can I retrieve this information server-side in Azure Web Apps?

You can only do that if your application is authorized to have access to that information, but you haven't told us that.

Yes, my application is authorized to access user group information. I am able to view user group using the /.auth/me endpoint on the client side. I'm looking for guidance on how to similarly retrieve this information on the server side.

What do you see when you use the MS Graph API?

Thank you for your response, Dai. While I am aware of the potential to use the Microsoft Graph API, I'm specifically looking for various options to retrieve Azure AD user group information directly server-side within an Azure Web App environment. I want to understand all possible methods that can be used, not just the MS Graph API. Any insights on different approaches or best practices for this would be greatly appreciated!

"directly server-side within an Azure Web App environment." - May I ask what gives you the impression that Azure exposes that kind of information to AppServices? (To my knowledge, it doesn't: there is no secret pipe from Entra to any AppService). Everything goes through the MSGraph now.

Thank you for pointing that out. My initial impression that such information might be directly accessible server-side came from the fact that the /.auth/me endpoint provides this information client-side. I assumed there might be a parallel or similar method available for server-side retrieval within Azure Web Apps.

I agree with @Dai, In an Azure Web App environment, direct server-side retrieval of Azure AD user group information isn't feasible. You need to make use of Microsoft Graph API.
Hence, in modify your code by calling the below Microsoft Graph API query to retrieve the signed in user's group memberships:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/transitiveMemberOf/microsoft.graph.group


transitiveMemberOf returns groups with respect to group nesting


If you want to fetch groups user is a direct member of, make use of below query:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf/microsoft.graph.group


Make sure to grant GroupMember.Read.All API permission to the Microsoft Entra ID application.
UPDATE:
To get the user information in Azure Web App, you can access the user claims from X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL in the header.It is the Base64 encoded JSON representation of available claims. Refer this MsDoc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-user-identities

This is incorrect. I am able to access the user claim from X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL in the header. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-user-identities

From server side?

Sorry for the misconception updated my answer
